# Jenkins: sign git tag using GPG key

Tags: git, jenkins, gnupg

As part of security configuration we want to implement "Verify Commit Signature" hook on a bitbucket. This should check that every git commit and tag signed with GPG key.

Meanwhile, our Jenkins jobs executes "git tag" commands. Now I have a problem to implement properly GPG sign on Jenkins tasks.
There is option to add Credentials for Jenkins, however there is only one such option and it's already in use for SSH key.

What you can recommend to implement GPG keys on Jenkins tasks?

- upload GPG key as a secret text or file directly to the Jenkins. Still unable to run multiple credentials - SSH + GPG key

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you already have GPG installed.
Steps:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

Then configure Git
`git config --global user.signingkey xxxxxx`(output from above line)

You must make some changes(I changed READ.me)

```
git commit -S -m 'Test commit'
git push
```

Just check the git log this way

```
git log --show-signature

commit fa3a2a7f11207d98ead4c8f631d72a611638004a (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
gpg: Signature made Fri 02 Dec 2022 08:40:28 AM CET
gpg:                using RSA key q11C2Eq2cS9F6D3Da425F3C71FA844F34DE11111
gpg: Good signature from "MMarkovic.ah <milenko.markovic@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
Author: MilenkoMarkovic <milenko.markovic@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 2 08:40:28 2022 +0100

    Test commit
```

You sign tags

```
git tag -s "v0.1" -m "first tag message"
```

Comment: 1. The OP asks how to upload GPG key **to Jenkins**. 2. Sign tags, not commits.

Comment: Yes, it's not an issue to modify personal settings to use GPG keys for commits. There is a challenge to setup GPG keys in Jenkins

Comment: @Stanislav Can you provide more info regarding your Jenkins setup(master.agent)? Why not git-crypt? Check this https://medium.com/@jon_gille/decrypting-secrets-in-your-ci-cd-pipeline-c57da11e1794.